# Matlab: passing more arguments to `nlinfit` function

Tags: matlab, arguments, parameter-passing

I am in interested in passing extra arguments to `nlinfit` function in Matlab

```
beta = nlinfit(X,Y,modelfun,beta0)
```

and let the `modelfun` is

```
function y = modelfun(beta, c, X)
y = beta(1)*x.^(beta2) + c;
```

My interest is estimate beta and also to provide `c` externally. X and Y have their obvious meanings.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `c` is a value generated before you call [`nlinfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) (i.e. its value is fixed while `nlinfit` is running), then you can use an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) wrapper to pass the extra parameter like so:

```
beta = nlinfit(X, Y, @(beta, X) modelfun(beta, c, X), beta0);
```